# Small scale aluminium tubes manufacturing

Tags: aluminum

Our startup needs short aluminuim tubes (max. ~70 cm [~27.5 inches] long / less than 1 cm / 0.4 inch diameter) such as these:

[image: Aluminium tubes]

We'd prefer to manufacture them ourselves rather than buy them from a s

Are there small scale solutions (machines, etc.) that would allow us to do this?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Are you just cutting the tubes to length? Are you machining some details into the tube? What is the length of the raw material? What type of precision do you require?

Comment: Are you taking flat sheet to roll and weld?

Comment: They are made by extrusion = Very High capitol costs. Welding of rolled sheet metal would require less equipment but substantial  labor time would be needed to weld and then grind the OD and ream the ID to make the wall thickness uniform.  The weld zone would be very soft unless heat-treated (  special consideration would be needed to select a filler metal to be heat-treatable). I have heard of traditional aluminum filler metals referred to as having the strength of chewing gum (metallurgy humor).

Answer (score 1):

There are some smaller extruders out there. You say less than .4", the standard OD's should be easy to find (.188", .250" and .375"). If you're needing something other than those, it's going to get pricey quick. Our biggest customers get the biggest price break, but those are major tier 1 automotive parts suppliers ordering 5 million+ pounds per year. If you're only needing a few pounds, it may be difficult to find an extruder. We sell tons (literally) to distributors all over the nation. You might search for aluminum tube distributors.